# JS не ищет свойства в __proto__, если объект создан с помощью Object.create(null)

Tags: javascript, объекты, prototype

Вот код:

```js
var o1 = Object.create(null);
o1.__proto__ = { x: 1 };
alert(o1.x); // undefined

var o2 = {};
o2.__proto__ = { x: 1 };
alert(o2.x); // 1

var o3 = Object.create(null);
Object.setPrototypeOf(o3, { x: 1 })
alert(o3.x); // 1

var tmp = Object.create(null);
tmp.x = 1;
var o4 = Object.create(null);
Object.setPrototypeOf(o4, tmp);
alert(o4.x); // 1
// console.dir(o4) -> No Properties
```

Почему `o1.x != 1`?

Comment: вот поэтому и не стоит использовать недокументированные возможности :-)

Comment: http://www.2ality.com/2015/09/proto-es6.html#objects_that_dont_have_object.prototype_as_a_prototype

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Немного разверну соседний ответ:

Если посмотреть спецификацию, можно заметить описание [свойства __proto__](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.prototype.__proto__)

Это пара методов [`get`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-get-object.prototype.__proto__), [`set`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-set-object.prototype.__proto__) эквивалентных по вызовам функциям [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.getprototypeof),[`Object.setPrototypeOf`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.setprototypeof)

Особо стоит обратить внимание на то, что это в действительности

```
Object.prototype.__proto__
```

То есть, это свойство описано в **прототипе Object**.

При создании же объекта с помощью `Object.create(null)` данного свойства в прототипе созданного объекта нет, и оно присваивается только как обычное поле.

Если вас интересуют подробности реализации прототипов в ES6, то можете почитать [статью Axel Rauschmayer](http://www.2ality.com/2015/09/proto-es6.html).

---

[**Важное дополнение:**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-additional-ecmascript-features-for-web-browsers)

Дополнение к спецификации, в котором описано данное свойство указывает, что все что в нем определено обязательно реализовано, если код выполняется в браузере. Но в других системах описанные конструкции могут отсутствовать.

Кроме того, в этом дополнении описаны особенности и характеристики унаследованные от реализаций ECMAScript в браузерах. Описанные языковые особенности и поведение имеют один или несколько нежелательных характеристик и будут удалены из данной спецификации по мере возможности. Однако использование на огромном количестве веб страниц заставляет браузеры до сих пор поддерживать их.

[*Эти особенности **не являются** основной частью языка ECMAScript. Программисты **не должны** использовать их или полагаться на их наличие при написании нового кода.*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-additional-ecmascript-features-for-web-browsers)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43298/discussion-on-answer-by-grundy-js-----proto---).

Answer (score 1):

Имо вы создаёте структуру подобную объекту но без нативных методов объекта, т.к. прототипом объекта созданого с помощью `Object.create(null)` будет `null`. [Документация Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)

```
    var o1 = Object.create(null);
        console.log('o1.__proto__', o1.__proto__); // выведет в консоль undefined
        o1.__proto__ = { x: 1 };
        o1 instanceof Object-->false

        alert(o1.x); // undefined
        var o2 = {};
        console.log(o2.__proto__); // выведет в консоль Object {} c функциями объекта как-то 
                                   //constructor function Object() { [native code] }
                                   //hasOwnProperty: function hasOwnProperty() { [native code] }
                                   //isPrototypeOf: function isPrototypeOf() { [native code] }         
        o2.__proto__ = { x: 1 };
        alert(o2.x); // 1
```

Comment: обрати внимание, что присваивается целиком объект, а не какое-то одно свойство

Comment: @grundy дополнил