# Почему свойство prototype необходимо писать снаружи функции

Tags: javascript, prototype

кто знает объясните пожалуйста почему f.prototype = prototype; пишется не внутри функции-конструкторе а снаружи. Пробовал присваивать прототип как снаружи так и внутри функции но работает только когда снаружи, код для примера:

```js
    function Menu(option){
        this.option = option;
    }
    Menu.prototype = {
        width: 200,
        height: 300,
        constructor: Menu
    }
    let submenu = new Menu("Secondary");
    console.log(submenu.width);// покажет 200
    //но если свойство menu.prototype перенести в функцию то при создании нового объекта 
    //он не будет иметь доступа к свойствам прототипа(потому как будет считаться
    //обычным свойством, но разве .prototype не является свойством которое 
    //имеет каждая функция), отсюда и вопрос: Почему свойство prototype пишется
    //только снаружи функции?(не могу дальше пройти пока не пойму почему так,
    //кто знает подскажите или направьте в нужном направлении)
```

Comment: покажи пример для _свойство menu.prototype перенести в функцию то при создании нового объекта 
    //он не будет иметь доступа к свойствам прототипа_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Когда вы пишете `function Menu` вы объявляете функцию, а не
  вызываете. Иными словами, в момент объявления функции, вы не
  изменяете прототип. И в момент ее первого вызова, прототип у нее
  пустой.
- Кроме этого, вы будете перезаписывать прототип при каждом запуске функции.

Смотри пример

```js
function Menu(option) {
  this.option = option;
  Menu.prototype = {
    width: 200,
    height: 300
  };
}

console.log("Menu.prototype до запуска", Menu.prototype)
let menu1 = new Menu("menu1")
console.log("Menu.prototype после", Menu.prototype)

//пытаемся обратиться к свойству Width, оно же есть в прототипе
console.log("Width menu1: " + menu1.width) //unendified

//создаем второе меню
let menu2 = new Menu("menu2")

//и внезапно свойство появляется
console.log("Width menu2: " + menu2.width) //200
```

Comment: Спасибо, именно ваш комментарий помог разобраться

Answer (score -2):

На самом деле, свойство называется `__proto__` и оно указывается внутри функции конструктора.

```js
var animal = {
  eats: true
};

function Rabbit(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.__proto__ = animal;
}

var rabbit = new Rabbit("Кроль");

alert( rabbit.eats ); // true, из прототипа
```

F.prototype - это альтернативная запись того же `__proto__`, но указывается снаружи функции конструктора. Разница в том, что `__proto__` не поддерживается IE10- и все.

> При создании объекта через new, в его прототип `__proto__` записывается
>   ссылка из prototype функции-конструктора.
>
> Установка Rabbit.prototype = animal буквально говорит интерпретатору
>   следующее: "При создании объекта через new Rabbit запиши ему `__proto__`
>   = animal".

Comment: _`F.prototype` - это альтернативная запись того же `__proto__`_ - нет, это разные вещи

Comment: Альтернатива - это и есть разные вещи, которые в данном случае делают одно и тоже. Тема различий прото и прототайп уже давно обсуждалась в другом топике https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/765445/%d0%92-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b5-proto-%d0%be%d1%82-prototype

Comment: они не могут делать одно и то же и том топике как раз было про их различие. Про `__proto__` лучше [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/550768/186999) смотреть